# UITableView Custom Cells Not Showing Up

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with two IBOutlet's to two different UITableViewCell's that were made in IB. However they are not showing up in the tableView. If you can find the error, I will really appreciate it.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *categoryIdentifier = @"Category";
    static NSString *songDetailsCellIdentifier = @"sdci";
    static NSString *socialCellIdentifier = @"sdcssi";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            //imageView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            //songNameLabel.text = songName;
            //artistNameLabel.text = artistName;
            //albumNameLabel.text = albumName;
            //numberInChartsLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", numberInCharts];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:categoryIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Category"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", category];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Preview This Track"];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"View This Song In iTunes"];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"View Artist In iTunes"];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        songDetailsCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:songDetailsCell.frame reuseIdentifier:songDetailsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        return songDetailsCell;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        socialCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:socialCell.frame reuseIdentifier:socialCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        return socialCell;
```

}
        else if (indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <=5)
    { 
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the switch in an `if{indexPath.section}` statetment, including the `UITableViewCell *cell...`

Then the rest below that needs to be `indexPath.section`, instead of `indexPath.row`

```
if(indexPath.section==0) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:

....


 if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    songDetailsCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:songDetailsCell.frame reuseIdentifier:songDetailsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    return songDetailsCell;
}


....
```

Follow that format.

Comment: turns out it was because I was not loading the nib in the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly then there is not a way for the system to know that you have a custom cell. Your cells are alloc'd and init'd with UITableViewCell as the type. They should be of the type of MyCustomCell or whatever you called your cell objects when you created them in Interface Builder.

So, you would reference your cell instead of UITableViewCell in this section of your code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

There is a [great, free screencast](http://pragmaticstudio.com/screencasts) that Pragmatic Studio did on making custom table cells. It's called Custom Table Cells in Interface Builder. It's about 20 minutes.